# What is the difference between ng-click and data-ng-click in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

From 1st view seems like `data-ng-click` can pass some data as argument to method should be invoked during pressing on button.

But I don't see the difference.

I have followed snippets of code:

**HTML**

```
<input 
    type="button" 
    value="Fess"
    ng-click="toggle(2)">
```

OR

```
<input 
    type="button" 
    value="Fess"
    data-ng-click="toggle(2)">
```

**JS**

```
$scope.toggle = function (valueS) {
    alert(valueS);        
}
```

Both work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 36, accepted):

They are the same thing. You can use `data-ng-click` to make a valid html.

Comment: You will get `Attribute ng-click not allowed on element input at this point.` if you pass it through html validator. While `data-ng-click` is a valid attribute in html5.

Answer (score 13):

From the [angular docs on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Directives have camel cased names such as ngBind. The directive can be
>   invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these
>   special characters :, -, or _. Optionally the directive can be
>   prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant. Here
>   is a list of some of the possible directive names: ng:bind, ng-bind,
>   ng_bind, x-ng-bind and data-ng-bind.

Leaving them out is totally fine for practical purposes.  It's just that if you run it through an html validator service, it will not pass as complliant.

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 has an ability to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements

These new custom data attributes consist of two parts:

**Attribute Name**
The data attribute name must be at least one character long and must be prefixed with 'data-'. It should not contain any uppercase letters.

**Attribute Value**
The attribute value can be any string.

```
<li data-spacing="30cm" data-sowing-time="February to March">Celery</li>
```

source : http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 4):

Found a difference while using with and without Form.

When my element is in a Form they act the same.

When I use `data-ng-click` on an element not within a form, Click event is not happening.