# Why ng-click not working in the example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I can see that on clicking the control not going to controller by chrome debugger. I have simple code in view and controller. Also, I am not getting any error. Any help would be appreciated.

**View**

```
<div class="logInBtn">
   <a data-ng-click="submitLoginDetails()">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
   </a>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('loginPageController',function($scope, $http, assimilationSurveyService){

    $scope.submitLoginDetails = function(){

        $scope.loginData = {
          "password": "pass1234",
          "userId": "userabc"
        };

        assimilationSurveyService.sendLoginData($scope.loginData)
            .success(function(data) {
                alert("Hi!");
            });
    }

});
```

**Router**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider

    .when('/loginPage', {title:'Feedback',templateUrl:'loginPage.html',controller:'loginPageController'})

    .otherwise({title:'Feedback', templateUrl:'loginPage.html'});
}])
```

**Service**

```
app.service('assimilationSurveyService',function(){

    return{

            // For Getting expense list
            sendLoginData: function(loginData) {
                var sendLoginData = {
                    url: 'http://172.16.34.245:8080/Survey/user/login',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: loginData,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                };

                return $http(sendLoginData);
            },


    }

});
```

The pointer is not coming to controller when login button is clicked. So just let me know why on ng-click I am not getting the program to come to the controller part.

> Even when I remove anchor and set the ng-click in button, I am not being redirected to controller code function. Strange issue!

Comment: data-ng-click? I use ng-click. I should add too that a button inside an anchor is pretty strange. I would put it all on the button element.

Comment: look what he said:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34527897/5393271)

Comment: ng-click is also not getting the flow get to controller. Actually, ng-click is not  taking the controller to my controller, so no success message.

Comment: Could you include the html tag with `ng-controller` .

Comment: This is a routing page. So controller coming in routing file not in html itself.

Comment: Use This Code `<a href="javascript:void(0)">
     <button type="button" data-ng-click="submitLoginDetails()" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
   </a>`

Comment: Still not worked.

Comment: Does not work. I think there is some silly mistake.

Comment: the `ng-controller` is binded to `loginPageController` parent DOM ? `ng-app` binded too ?

Comment: try to put the controller code in the same file with the router; I've encounter this problem but I've had self invoking functions - not with "app."

Comment: Kiro --> In routing ng-route the controller is defined in routing config only. sTx --> file is already added. Code in same file or else, does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was simple:

This view was getting default loaded so controller was not getting bind to it.

The solution should have been:

```
.otherwise({title:'Feedback', templateUrl:'loginPage.html',controller:'loginPageController'});
```

In otherwise I missed giving controller, and since this was the first and also default page, it took otherwise but as no controller was there in it, it wasn't able to connect ng-click to the respective controller.

Thanks all for helping though ... It really helped me debug the problem!